# Compiling LaTex bib source

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texworks

I am writing my thesis (thesis.tex) in Latex, and I have the references in an own reference.bib file which look as follows

```
@Article{xxx,
  author =       "D.A. Reinhard",
  title =        "Case Study",
  year =         "1985",
}
```

and I reference them in my main document as `\cite{xxx}`

I am using Texworks on Windows. After compiling the bib to generate a bbl, when I compile then thesis.tex with: pdflatex +MakeIndex + BibTex, I am able to see the pdf of 'thesis', but I do not see the Bibilography section at the end and do not see references to the bibliography, not even question marks instead of the proper references to the bibliography.

When I tried pdflatex + BibTex + pdflatex + pdflatex, the 'References' section shows up at the end, but I do not see the references (such as 1. Reinhard, D.A. Case Study ). I also do not see the citation in the paper

I did include `\bibliography{relativepath/reference}` at the end of `thesis.tex`

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you defined the style? If not try adding `\bibliographystyle{plain}` somewhere in the document.
The order of typesetting is: pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your description is a bit cryptic for me. Did you run pdflatex afterwards to incorporate the contents of the bbl into the pdf? How are you includeing the bibliography? Can you show us a short but compilable example? That is important, because what to do depends on the basic setup.

Comment: Do you have any `\cite` commands in the document?

Comment: Also for testing `\nocite{*}` gives you all the references

Comment: why do I have to do 'pdflatex' twice after 'bibtex'? When I tried that, the 'References' section shows up at the end, but I do not see the references (such as `1. Reinhard, D.A. Case Study `). I also do not see the citation in the paper

Comment: I include the bibliography by typing `\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{"C:/Users/reference"}`. I ran it in the order Jonas suggested, pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex. Yes, I have a `\cite command`, such as in the introduction section when I type `\cite{xxx}`

Comment: I doubt very much that you can specify your `.bib` file like that. That is ***not*** a `relativepath` but an absolute one. Try moving `reference.bib` into your working directory (where your `.tex` file is). Rerun pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex. Does it work now?

Comment: pdfTeX needs two compilations to resolve the references after you've run bibTeX. It needs to get all of the information into the right files in the right places. (bibLaTeX may only need one compilation, at least in some cases, but I would not suggest trying to switch at this point.)

Comment: The `reference.bib` is already in the same directory as the `.tex`. It didn't matter what path I used for the bib. Even when I just entered `\bibliography{reference}`, it still didn't work

Comment: I think it is time for clarifying the question by showing us the contents of your log-file and blg-file. We *need* to know what you are doing to help you.